# How to allow user to change download path?

Tags: c#, winforms, path, download

I'm working on a Winform project,

I have a panel(`PNLdownload`) the user can download by pressing a button, here's the code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PNLdownload.Width, PNLdownload.Height + 120);
PNLdownload.DrawToBitmap(bmp, PNLdownload.Bounds);
bmp.Save(@"C:\Test\Test.bmp");
```

I want the user to be able to choose where to download the image, how can I do this?

I couldn't find a way to do this on the web

Comment: What kind of app is this (console, WinForms, WPF, etc.)?

Comment: @Flydog57 seems to be Winforms since I didn't see another UI framework that has a panel class with a DrawToBitmap method, but hopefully the author can clarify.

Comment: Winforms: There are a Dialogues just for that..: Choose between [SaveFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) to allow picking path and name and [FolderBrowserDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) to pick just a folder

Comment: It's Winforms, sorry for not specifying

Comment: @LucOliSil could you update your question and add the "winforms" **tag** as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [SaveFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-5.0).

Adapting the sample code at the provided link yields:

```cs
Stream myStream;
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PNLdownload.Width, PNLdownload.Height + 120);
PNLdownload.DrawToBitmap(bmp, PNLdownload.Bounds);

saveFileDialog1.Filter = "*.bmp";
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
    {
        bmp.Save(myStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        myStream.Close();
    }
}
```